# Does anyone know how to update intel HAXM from version 7.6.5 to 7.8.0 in Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1 (Windows 10)

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Does anyone know how to force update Intel HAXM in the latest Android Studio for Windows as this version of Android Studio only seems to install an outdated version?

I have tried adding a repositories.cfg file linking to the latest HAXM file update in github but it does not pickup at all. I have used ChatGPT (not suppose to mention here) to look for solutions but nothing works. I want for the emulators to work smoothly in AVDManager without any lag or the GPU Driver Issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit with this site's goals & objectives, since it isn't related to programming issue.

Comment: Well it does relate to android studio programming since I want to code a mobile application. Surely someone who uses android studio who are testing their apps via avdmanager, would want to run their emulators smoothly when testing (unless I am wrong)